# Clustered application using one message queue

Tags: jms

I have a clustered application, same application on two different servers, behind a load balancer.
I only have one JMS queue.
Will the queue make sure that a message is read only once, since both deployed applications will read from the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, only one of the application will get a message from a JMS queue. The message will be removed from the queue when client application acknowledges the received message. So the same message will NOT be delivered to other instance of the clustered application.